# Trigger Click for Context Menu in JQuery

Tags: jquery, contextmenu

I'm using [jQuery Context Menu plugin](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/09/jquery-context-menu-plugin/).

I have the following:

```
$('div').contextMenu({
    menu: 'menu'
},function(action, el, pos) {
    //some statements
});
```

How to activate it when a user 'click' instead of just right click?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LOL

I was going to say: change plugin code, line 40

```
if( evt.button == 1 ) {
```

to

```
if( true ) {
```

Comment: I saw `evt.button == 2` instead.

Comment: Sorry, I changed it in the console to test it and then copied the changed line instead of the original. Well, at least I got the line number right and my point across. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

```
$('div').click(function(){
$("").contextMenu({
    menu: 'menu'
},function(action, el, pos) {
    //some statements
});
});
```

this should work fine

Comment: didn't work. What i want is to show the `context menu` when `div` is `clicked`

Comment: i just edit my post... i replace bind to click.. cause bind sometimes has a problem and also the tagget where to show the contextMenu and where do you want the context menu to show

Comment: it won't work either. When `clicked`, it just assigned the context menu when clicked.